# logging dhcp leases to syslog server on cisco router

Tags: cisco, dhcp

Is there any way of a cisco router acting as a dhcp server to record the leases of its clients to a syslog server?

I'm currently using the DHCP server database agent feature to record the leases to a file through a ftp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
debug ip dhcp server events
logging trap debugging
```

oughta do it.

yes, there may be unintended consequences if you enable other debugging while troubleshooting some other problem (for instance).

see also: [how to make debugging settings persist across a router reboot](http://blog.ioshints.info/2007/06/re-enable-debugging-on-router-reload.html)

Comment: Also I've also tried that debug but problem was with the reloads. The link you posted suggests using Event Manager Applet. Unfortunately my current IOS doesn't support 'action'.

Comment: Sure, but did you read the comment on that blog article? It suggests a hacky workaround if you don't have EEM.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the only way to get them in IOS would be to turn on DHCP debugging, which can't be done as part of the boot configuration.

Any reason you can't use ISC DHCPD on a running server and have the cisco act as a DHCP relay?

Comment: I know I could use another DHCPD server but in this particular case I have to use the cisco.
Thanks for the suggestion though.